# Clear the table of a database

Tags: c#, html, database, architecture

I am working on understanding 3 layered architecture and I am having a problem.
I do know how to insert data into my database, but I do not know how to delete all the info within the table with the push of a button.
My DAL:

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class ClsDataLayer
    {
        SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = Testdatabase; Integrated Security = True");

                public List<Gebruiker> Testlijst()
        {
            string commandText_Testlijst = "Select ID, Locatie,DatumTijd from Userinfo2";
            List<Gebruiker> Gebruikers = new List<Gebruiker>();
            using (SqlConn)
            {
                SqlConn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText_Testlijst, SqlConn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var gebruiker = new Gebruiker
                            {
                                ID = reader.GetInt64(0),
                                Locatie = reader.GetString(1),
                                DatumTijd = reader.GetDateTime(2)
                            };
                            Gebruikers.Add(gebruiker);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return Gebruikers;
            ;

        }



        public bool VoegToeGebruiker(string locatie, DateTime DatumTijd)
        {
            using SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = Testdatabase; Integrated Security = True");
            SqlConn.Open();

            using var command = SqlConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Insert into Userinfo2 (Locatie,DatumTijd) values (@locatie, @DatumTijd)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locatie", locatie);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumTijd", DatumTijd);
            var editLines = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (editLines == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public bool VerwijderGebruiker()
        {
            using SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = Testdatabase; Integrated Security = True");
            SqlConn.Open();

            using var command = SqlConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Delete From Userinfo2";
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                var verwijderLines = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (verwijderLines == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }


        }
public class Gebruiker
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Locatie { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumTijd { get; set; }

    }

    }
```

My BLL:

```
namespace BLL
{

    public class CLSBussLayer
    {
        ClsDataLayer objDal = new ClsDataLayer();

        public List<Gebruiker> GetGebruikers()
        {
            return objDal.Testlijst();

        }

        public bool Addgebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker)
        {
            return objDal.VoegToeGebruiker(gebruiker.Locatie, gebruiker.DatumTijd);
            //if statements voor verifieren van ingevulde data moeten hier
        }
        public bool Verwijdergebruiker()
        {
            return objDal.VerwijderGebruiker();
        }

    }
```

My index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string Locatie { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime DatumTijd { get; set; }


        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
           bussLayer = new CLSBussLayer();
        }
        private CLSBussLayer bussLayer{get; set;}

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            bussLayer.Addgebruiker(new Gebruiker
            {
                Locatie = Locatie,
                DatumTijd = DatumTijd

            }) ;

        }
    }
```

my index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
        BLL.CLSBussLayer bussLayer = new BLL.CLSBussLayer();
    var list = bussLayer.GetGebruikers();
}
    <link href="~/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@foreach (Modellayer.Gebruiker gebruiker in list)
{
    <div>
        @gebruiker.Locatie
        @gebruiker.DatumTijd

    </div>
}

<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="name">Naam: </label><br />
        <input type="text" id="naam" asp-for="Locatie" />
        <label for="Datetime">Datum: </label>
        <input value="05-19-2020T12:00" min="05-19-2020T12:00" type="datetime-local" id="DateTime" asp-for="DatumTijd" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type=""
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make a button (in my index.html) with the text DELETE that executes the VerwijderGebruiker method. 
I think I successfully made the delete method and passed it to the BLL but I don't know where to go from there.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hı ,

add button in your cshtml like  this.

```
@foreach (Modellayer.Gebruiker gebruiker in list)
{
    <div>
        @gebruiker.Locatie
        @gebruiker.DatumTijd

    </div>
 <button onclick="DeleteItem(@gebruiker.ID)">Delete</button>
}
```

then , in your javascript define DeleteItem metod  and post ajax. (give your delete action url)

```
<script>
function DeleteItem(Id) {
$('#btnDlete').on('click', function () {
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ str: Id}); //strigify json data
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //set content type
    url: "YourController/DeleteRecord", //remove the first slash from the url
    data: jsonData,
    async: false, //wheather to call async or not
    success: function (data) {
          alert('success'); //success handler
    },
    error: function (data) {
          alert(data); //error handler
    }
  });
}
</script>
```